# MS Bot Framework - Bot as a Service, connecting clients to data. Need one bot per SaaS instance?

Tags: botframework

Trying to decide how to implement MS Bot Framework.
Working for SaaS company, we want to have chatbot layer on our app.
Client should be able to interact with chatbot, run queries, get results, like psudoreporting.

I developed a proof of concept, and it works well, but that is only for one connection string to one client, but the bot and it's code would be one bot, for all clients?

I can see how we can do it with one bot, per SaaS instance, but that would mean 100+ reuse and duplication and maintenance of various bot code bases ...

Thoughts / best practices?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that at some point a user talking to your bot is authenticated. It might be via the SigninCard or other means. As you authenticate your user, you are able to get information to which SaaS instance the user belongs to and therefor you know a corresponding user database. You can store this information (encrypted) in the user private data store in the botframework. If your SaaS already has API that is provides necessary information for authenticated user, then it is enough just to have the user authenticated when you do calls to your API from the bot.